# Path of a new page in PHP SocialEngine

Tags: socialengine

Can anyone tell me how to find path/root of a new page I have done in SocialEngine PHP?

Like: `public_html/site/application`, where I want to password the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
[yourDomain]/pages/[yourPage]
```

The page data is stored in the database in the engine4_core_pages table. There is no physical presence on the file structure. You can add widgets to the page, and those will have files under the application/widgets folder.